# CakePHP: Friendly urls using inflector and no id

Tags: php, cakephp

I have built a simple portfolio using CakePHP and it has urls like: `domain.com/portfolio/82/This_is_an_item`

What I want to do is remove the ID from the url. How would I do this?

Here is my controller code for the view:

```
function view ( $id, $slug )
{
    $post = $this->Portfolio->read(null, $id));

    $this->set(compact('post'));
}
```

and here is the link generator:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Portfolio']['title'],
        array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'view', $post['Portfolio']['id'], Inflector::slug($post['Portfolio']['title'])),
        array('title' => $post['Portfolio']['title'])); ?>
```

I'm guessing I need to change the controller method to do some sort of find on the title?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the id completely, but you'll have to make sure the slugs are unique (specify inUnique validation rule is a option). When saving the post, use `Inflector::slug()` on the 'title' field (you might want to save it to a 'slug' field, if you want to keep the title intact:

`$this->data['Portfolio']['slug'] = Inflector::slug($this->data['Portfolio']['title'])`

> ```
> function view ($slug ){
>    $post = $this->Portfolio->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Portfolio.slug'=>$slug))));
>    $this->set(compact('post'));
> }
> ```

and for the link:

> ```
> <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Portfolio']['title'],
>     array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'view', $post['Portfolio']['slug']),
>     array('title' => $post['Portfolio']['title']));
> ```

Comment: This looks good. Could you show me how I would save the slug though? As I take it to do this properly I will have a title field and a slug field in the database? Cheers

Comment: I edited the answer. And yes to the second question, because you can't get back the title after slugging it.

Answer (score 2):

I would save the slug in the database, along with the title. That way you only have to create it once. Also you may or may not be able to get a unique link from slug to title, so it's best not to try.

For easy processing you can use the Sluggable behaviour, see https://gist.github.com/338096 (or just Google).

**Update**

If you use the sluggable behaviour from https://gist.github.com/338096 (save as sluggable.php in app/model/behaviors), you would only need to do a few steps:

In your Profile model class add `var $actsAs = array('Sluggable');` or

```
var $actsAs = array(
    'Sluggable' => array(
        'fields' => 'title',
        'scope' => false,
        'conditions' => false,
        'slugfield' => 'slug',
        'separator' => '-',
        'overwrite' => false,
        'length' => 256,
        'lower' => true
    )
);
```

if you want to override settings

In the database, add a column `slug` in the profiles table.

When you save a profile, it will automagically add fill in the slug field, you do not need to take any special actions.

Comment: How would I create a slug like the title, save it to the DB and then use it as the url? Code examples would be awesome :) Thanks

Comment: Could I not just save the inflected title in a new column called 'slug' and then use that as the url? If so how would I do this without needing to use the sluggable behaviour?

Comment: FYI, CakeDC's [Utils plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils) also comes with a [SluggableBehavior](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/master/models/behaviors/sluggable.php) (among other things).

Comment: @Cameron, that is exactly what these behaviors do. Reinvent the wheel if you want though. :)

Comment: What would I put in my controller for the add and edit methods to save the inflected title in the slug column?

Comment: You don't need to put anything in your controller. Just attach the behavior to the model, and it will know that it should use the title to create a slug. The slug is created automatically when you save a record, so you can't forget it.